# Which is a efficient way to query a database in Grails? SQL, HQL or GORM?

Tags: sql, grails, grails-orm, processing-efficiency

I am working on a application where I need to query(simple as well as complex) on a database many times.

I can understand that for simple queries there won't be a substantial difference between any of the approach mentioned above.

I would like know the efficient way in case of semi complex and complex queries.

Suppose I have a `Domain` class say

```
    Class Sample{
          String firstName
          String lastName
          long   timeStamp
   }
```

Now, I want to get the **latest two records**.So either I can write an

1. `SQL query`

   ```
   select first_name, last_name from sample order by time_stamp desc limit 2;
   ```
2. `HQL` query

   ```
   String queryString = "select firstName, lastName from Sample order by timeStamp desc"

   List sampleList = Sample.executeQuery(queryString, [max: 2, offset: 0])
   ```
3. `GORM` query

   ```
   def list    =   Sample.list(max: 2, sort: "timeStamp", order: "desc")
   ```

Out of this which will be the efficient way to query a database?

Answer (score 1):

There is no significant difference between these 3. If you turn on query logging you should see that the SQL is virtually the same in all 3 cases.

However, if using HQL or GORM you can cache the results of the query. This might lead to greater efficiency if the query frequently returns the same results. On the other hand if the query rarely returns the same results (e.g. because the `sample` table is frequently updated), enabling query caching may reduce efficiency.

Ultimately, worrying about performance at this level is likely a case of premature optimization. I'd advise doing the simplest thing, which is probably GORM in this case, and worry about performance only when a performance problem has been identified.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and most performant way would be to use dialect-specific SQL queries and no ORM at all.

In GORM/Hibernate there's no substantial differences between those ways, what is more important is the code readability. In this case the `criteria queries` win over SQL/HQL counterparts, unless `findAllBy*` can be applied.

Answer (score 1):

As injecteer mentioned before, the native SQL query is always the most efficient way to get the requested results.

All other approaches depend the implementation of the GORM-Datastore resp. the Query-mapping implementation. Both (the HQL and the critera) queries need to be translated to a native SQL-dialect (if using a SQL-Database) before the query is send to the database. In the given example both queries will result in the same native-SQL statement.